# How to change the Location of the JDK in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I tried to change the location by the following way

Project Structure > SDK location > JDK Location > ...

But it always reverts to the old address saved in it.

It's not saving the new location entered in it.

Please help me to solve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was because I had a whitespace (which I can see is your case) in my JDK path. Try changing your JDK path to something like C:\jdk_1.7.0

Comment: There is a no white space in the address i have entered and i want to change that to (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but it didn't work.                                               I want to change the address to this location (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92) but it always reverts to this location (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10), which does not exists in my PC.                               Because of this problem I'm unable to run the app by using USB Debugging. It show the following error                                              Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> compileSdkVersion 'android-24' requires JDK 1.8 or later to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Install the 32 bit java version. Problem will be resolved